# Android: Numbers Shifting in TableRow When Text is Updated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout with several TableRows in it. In each row, I have two TextViews: the first one displays some descriptive text and the second one displays a number. For example:

```
| Text |.0.|
| Text2|.0.|
| ...  |.0.|
```

I have the TextViews of equal weight, gravity is centered for both the row itself and each `TextView`, however, when the text is changed during the execution of the app the elements shift and are no longer lined up. So it becomes something like this:

```
| Text |..0|
| Text2|..0|
| ...  |..0|
```

where the values are no longer where they were initially. I would like the values to remain where they are while text changes (the longest text is not long enough that it comes close to the numbers). I would also like to keep the format neat and the SDK level as low as possible (currently it is at 8).

Sample xml code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8"
    tools:context=".Name" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </TableRow>

    // This is the start of where the descriptive text and their values are

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2-1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2-2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
     </TableRow>
... // etc
```

I have tried changing weights (assigning the first `TextView` weights of 9 and the second one of weight 1) but that did not work. I would like all of the numbers to be lined up and not shift when the text is changed, regardless of what it is (including the empty string "").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this in [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setShrinkAllColumns%28boolean%29)

```
TableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(boolean shrinkAllColumns)

TableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(boolean stretchAllColumns)
```

Comment: @lord_sneed But It seems that you gave us the wrong diagram for 2(1 and 2 are the same), I am not exactly sure which method you need to use. Ill update my answer after you clarfy.

Comment: The number in the right hand column is shifted over in the second one. I did not want to use symbols to represent spaces as that might be more confusing. The point is that the numbers (in the second column) are shifting around every time texts of different lengths are updated in the first column. I would like the number column to remain fixed (without shifting around) no matter what the text in the first column is changed to.

Comment: I updated the "figures" so the dots represent spaces in the number column. The numbers shift left and right depending on the string (whether it is the empty string, a short string, or a relatively long string).

Comment: Stretching the columns was part of the trick. The other thing I had to do (after a little bit more browsing) was set the width of the `TextView`s to "0dp". Thanks. Out of curiosity, have you done any network work with apps (device to device) and/or graphics?

Comment: Glad that helped. you should ask this in chat,if you want some general  question.  no for me.